# Importing Azure Communication Calling SDK in a Unity project

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to integrate Azure Communication Services into a Unity project. Ideally, it should also be able to interface with Microsoft Teams so using the Azure services is necessary.

At the moment, I am stuck on trying to import the SDK into the Unity project.

Here's what I have tried so far:

- importing the SDK package from the Nuget package manager in Unity. the Nuget package manager from Unity does not find the SDK
- importing the SDK package from the Nuget package manager in Visual Studio. in this context the Nuget package manager does find the SDK package but Unity fails to reference it
- building a dummy Visual Studio project that uses the SDK, and copying over the .dll files into the Unity Project. the problem is that using the SDK in this way seems quite cumbersome and counterintuitive, so I want to make sure that this is the only way before proceeding
- creating a class library in Visual Studio interfacing with the Azure Communication Service SDK. Visual Studio launched from Unity does recognize the SDK but when I try to run the game in Game Mode, I am greeted get this error `Could not load image H:\Coding\framework-sbs\Assets\Plugins\AzureCommunicationServicesWrapper\Azure.Communication.Calling.dll due to Invalid Section Aligmnent 1000`. It happens whenever any piece of code referencing the Calling SDK is executed.

Comment: Did anybody find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this: https://github.com/hololux/azure-communication-services-unity.
This is a plugin used to access acs services for teams calling in Unity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).